# Postman Tests: expect on SSL certificate expiry date

Tags: ssl-certificate, postman, health-monitoring, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

Is it possible to use Postman Monitors to check how many days the SSL certificate has left before it reaches its expiration date?

When creating a request in Postman it is possible to see a popup called "Network". It contains information such as TLS protocol, Cipher name, Issuer CN and most importantly Valid until.

Inspecting the `pm.` object in the Tests-tab and by reading through the documentation did not yield any apparent way to get this information programmatically.

Is there any trick to get the certificate in any way programmatically inside Postman? Either via another request, some variable or property that I didn't discover yet?